# Create a new Home page layout and assign a dashboard to it

Tags: reporting, dashboard, report-chart, home-page-layout

I have created a dashboard folder with two charts and I have given access to the folder to three user. Now what i want is that I want to create a new home page layout and assign that dashboard to that home page layout. I am not exactly sure how to achieve this. Can anyone tell me how to do this. I am very new in Salesforce and any help would be appreciated

Comment: this should get you started https://developer.salesforce.com/events/webinars/Lightning-App-Builder and remember you can always check for salesforce documentation at https://help.salesforce.com/ prior to posting questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps for your requirement.

1. Click on the Home tab and go to Dashboard section.

[image: dashboad]

2. Click on "Customize Page" link on the right side.
3. Choose your Dashboard in the "Customize Home Page" screen.

[image: Customize homepage]

4. Finally, you can assign the homepage to the respective profiles.